# Cosine similarity robust to shifts

Tags: distance, cosine-similarity

Is there a generalization of cosine similarity that is robust to shifts across the compared vectors? E.g. a metric assigning high similarity to the following vectors:

[0,1,1,1,2,2,0,0]
[1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0]

Comment: Can you be more specific with what "robust to shifts" means?

Comment: That accounts for misalignments of highly similar fractions of the compared feature vectors

Comment: Ah, as in everything was shifted one unit to the right...You may have to iteratively try some lags & leads of your data (a al cross-correlation). Obviously this can get computationally expensive, though.

Comment: This might be better suited for stats.stackexchange or dsp.stackexchange (signal processing)